# How to "$(document).ready()" on "frames"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I named "frames" the pages that contain some small content that I load multiple times in my php main page via AJAX on specific divs that will show up multiple times also in various places.

Real situation: I have a "Reply" div that contains all the replies to some message, and there is a "Reply" button that loads up a php page inside a div via AJAX with the Reply Input and form. I need to load a text editor on this input via javascript when this page loads up.

My problem is I use a `<script></script>` on every page that gets loaded:

```
<script>*Load text editor on inputs*</script>
```

And that loads it up fine, except when I keep opening that same pages again and again. Then it stops working.

When I look into the HTML to see what I'm getting I can't find the `<script></script>` that gets loaded with the page. It's like it didn't even load.

I don't think placing the `<script></script>` tags inside the php page is the best approach, I need to be able to create some kind of event that gets triggered when the pages gets loaded but without placing the `<script></script>` inside every page.

So here is the question: How to execute the action of loading the text editor via javascript when that page gets ready without placing a `<script></script>` inside every page?

I'm open to other approachs since this is very confusing to me and I don't know what are the best practices in this case.

Following real code (The page with the form tags is a php page with a "header" and "footer" which loads with every form).

reply_page.php:
(Notice that I use PHP to write the Id of the reply on the elements so they don't get the same name)

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert('it did get in here reply #<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3) ?>');

    load_tinymce(".tinymce<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3) ?>");

    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:999999999}, 'slow');
});

</script>  
<?php
        echo '<label>Reply*</label>';
        echo form_textarea(array('name'=>'reply-'.$text_add_itens, 'rows'=>'3',     'class'=>'form-control tinymce'.$this->uri->segment(3), 'id'=>'reply'), 
                '');

?>
```

function "load_tinymce":

```
function load_tinymce(where)
{
    tinymce.init({
        selector: where,
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
            "autolink lists link image hr anchor",
            "code",
            "media nonbreaking contextmenu directionality",
            ""
        ],
        toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        language: "pt_BR",
        document_base_url: url_base,
        relative_urls: true,  
        extended_valid_elements:"iframe[*],span[*],style[*]",
        content_css: url_base+"css/bootstrap.css",
        menubar:false,
        statusbar:false,
        forced_root_block : false,
    });         
}
```

My alert "'it did get in here..'" always get triggered with the right Id on it, BUT the text editor does not load on the first page loaded AFTER I load the second page. Meaning that only the last page loaded works.

UPDATE:

Performing some more tests I was able to observe that it is behaving like this:

I have 3 messages which opens up replies forms. 
I open the #1 message and open the reply form, the text editor gets loaded. 
I open the #2 message and the text editor gets loaded, all good.

When I go back to #1, and close and open the reply form again, the text editor DOES NOT load. Ok. So it got overwrited right?

I open the #3 message and open the reply form, the text editor DOES NOT get loaded anymore.

After the second time I opened the reply form, none of the forms I opened after gets the text editor BUT I can close and open that second form all I want and it works fine.

Comment: When you define, you looked into the HTML, did you inspect the current page, or did you open the source code by using the right click menu. Inspecting the real output should contain your scripttag, while the sourcecode shouldn't (it was part of the html that was sent to your browser). Reloading the same script several times on a page can also be cumbersome, and could break code that depends on the script (because the first script that linked to it, got overwritten, or reset). using JQuery, you can use getScript(), offering a callback when its loaded.  Could you show code that loads the div?

Comment: It is showing the script now, but it doesn't work because of it being in conflict with the other already on the document. I use a simple `$.ajax({success: function(html){ $(div).html(html); }});` to fill the div. Where would I use your getScript() sugestion?

Comment: and your html is containing the scriptblock? (meaning, the html you are getting back from the server ;))

Comment: Yes, for sure. On my HTML it has 2 scripts, one for each tab open. When I load another, only that one works, the others do not. I thought it was my reference to the class so I added the number of the page to the class when loading. For an example: I was loading my text editor on the class "input-text", so I added the number of the tab (that do not repeat) to the class: "input-text2" and I load that. But still not working. So I asked the question here to see if there are other approaches

Comment: The conflict was happening because although I had given an "Id" (number of the reply added to the class name: <a class="reply32"></a>) to each textarea I forgot to delete the attr "Id" (attr of the element like: <a id="reply"></a>) of them. I deleted the attr id of the elements and it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without really knowing how you call it, i could suggest following method. It first check if your script for editor was already loaded (in this case, jquery-ui), and if not loads it.

Once it is loaded, it also calls the function to show the dialog, if you click on another element (calling the same function), it doesn't reload, and simply calls the "editor" directly, the load function gets the div element as an argument, and this argument is added to the addEditorToScript function (in that case, as the this object)

**Update**

I made the update to use the tinymce. The script should go where you current jquery script is, the div should get a click event, and at least a unique id :) (it can be a textarea as well), does that help you better?

```js
function loadMe(divElement) {
  console.log(divElement.innerHTML);
  if (divElement && divElement.innerHTML.indexOf('<i>Click to reply</i>')) {
    divElement.innerHTML = '... loading, please wait ...';
    var callEditor = addEditorToScript.bind(divElement);
    if ($('#editorScript').length === 0) {
      console.log('loading jquery-ui');
      var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
      scriptTag.id = 'editorScript';
      scriptTag.src = 'http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js';
      $(scriptTag).on('load', callEditor);
      document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(callEditor, 0);
  }
}

function addEditorToScript() {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(arguments);
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#' + this.id
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>Lorem</h1>
  <p>
    Ipsum
  </p>
  <div id="editor1" onclick="loadMe(this)">
    <i>Click to reply</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Delorem</h1>
  <p>
    Something
  </p>
  <div id="editor2" onclick="loadMe(this)">
    <i>Click to reply</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But where would I place this piece of code? If I place it on my .js document it wouldn't get triggered since my page gets loaded way after the .js gets loaded (The element do not exist when I load my .js files and it may never exist at all). And If I place it on my page itseft, wouldn't it generate the same conflict with the other pages loaded?

Comment: @VictorHugo Could you edit your original post, showing some more precise steps on how you are currently reacting? I would suggest that the loadMe should be on the main page and gets called to load your editor. As that would then also have the target div element, you can use this one to create the editor script (instead of based on classes). But your question is slightly to abstract for me to really imagine what could go wrong, or where it goes wrong, show some code :)

Comment: I edited my question with some codes and some clarifications, thanks for the effort by the way

Comment: @VictorHugo I updated my reply (before i saw your last update)

Comment: I liked your approach and modified my structure to load the text editor after loading the ajax call (on the success function). Same problem. So I placed a button on my reply page: "Load tinymce". I set the "onclick" to run the "load_tinymce" function with the name of the class I want to load. Guess what? Same problem. The first time it works, If I don't load other pages it works forever. But when I load another page only that page works and even if I load a third page, only the second page work. :( Note: the load_tinymce function in inside my .js document, indepedent of the page itself.